# What's the purpose of "Away" here?

Tags: grammar

> Armand: I was just thinking what you said about Vincent laughing
> around and drinking with those lads on the day of his death.
> Where was that?
>
> Woman: Well it was right here, exactly here. Scribbling and scrawling
> **away** he was as always.

What's the purpose of "Away" here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/away) provides this definition and 3 examples. The first example is precisely on point:

> **away *adverb* (CONTINUOUSLY)**
>
> continuously or repeatedly, or in a busy way:
>
> *I was still writing away when the exam finished.*
> *Chris has been working away in the garden all day.*
> *We were chatting away at the back and didn't hear what he said.*